# How to display image in canvas at the position of my mouse cursor?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

How can I display image in a `canvas` at the `position` of my mouse cursor so that it can move around with my `mouse` movement.

Here is the code but it does not work:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
context = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMoved);
context.fillText("Put mouse here", 10, 10);

function mouseMoved(e) {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    var imageObj = new Image();

    imageObj.src = "avatar.png";
    imageObj.onload = function() {
        context.drawImage(imageObj, e.clientX - (canvas.offsetLeft - window.pageXOffset), e.clientY - (canvas.offsetTop - window.pageYOffset)], 224, 320);
};

// the following code that displays a still image works.
/*var imageObj = new Image();

imageObj.src = "avatar.png";
imageObj.onload = function() {
context.drawImage(imageObj, 225, 100, 224, 320);
};*/
}
```

```html
text<br/>
text<br/>
text<br/>
text<br/>
text<br/>
text<br/>
text<br/>
text<br/>
text<br/>
<canvas id="mycanvas" width="800" height="450", position: relative></canvas>
text<br/>
text<br/>
text<br/>
text<br/>
text<br/>
text<br/>
text<br/>
text<br/>
```

If I use the code that is currently out it will work. However that is just a still image. I want to be able to move the image around with my mouse cursor. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the square bracket here and it works

```
window.pageYOffset)], 224, 320);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sjmcpherso/dnt12psm/